# UIActivityViewController options are not clickable and scrollable

Tags: ios, swift, share, popover, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using the below code to show a popOver to share with options.
But options are not touchable but work with long press and also the "Edit option..." at the bottom of it is not clickable.

Here is the code :

```
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: self.docToShare, applicationActivities: [])            
        
        if let popOver = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
            popOver.sourceView = self.view
            popOver.sourceRect = exportView.frame
        }
        
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you show your code? iPhone or iPad?

Comment: try to use DispatchQueue.main.asyn{

Comment: @aheze Thanks! I am using iPad.

Comment: Your `sourceView` and `sourceRect` might be wrong. Try `popOver.sourceView = exportView; popOver.sourceRect = exportView.bounds`